# strange OOP behavior with $this->function();?

Tags: php, oop

I have this code (two classes)

```
class url
{
        private $profile_id;
        private $short;
        public $notice;
        private $forbidden;
        function url() {
                $this->forbidden = array('index.php', 'index.html', 'styles.css', 'style.css');
                if ($_POST['profile_id']){
//                      global $db;
                        $exists = db::fetch_one(db::query("SELECT count(1) FROM ".TABLE." WHERE profile_id = ".intval($_POST['profile_id']).";"));
                        $exists_username = db::fetch_one(db::query("SELECT count(1) FROM ".TABLE." WHERE url_short = '".db::mres($_POST['url_short'])."'"));
                }
        }
}

class db
{
        function db(){
                mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "h1gh§c1a0");
                mysql_select_db("gplus") or die(mysql_error());
                mysql_set_charset("utf8") or die(mysql_error());
        }

        function query($query){
//              print_r( $this);
                $result = mysql_query(self::protect($query)) or _log("Query failed: ".$query);
                //$this isn't working
                //$result = mysql_query($this->protect($query)) or _log("Query failed: ".$query);
                 return $result;

        }

        function fetch($result){
                $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                return $result;
        }

        function fetch_one($result){
                $result = mysql_fetch_row($result);
                return $result['0'];
        }


        function mres($text) {
                return mysql_real_escape_string($result);
        }

        function protect($text) {

                if (preg_match("/UNION/i", $text)) {
                        _log("Hack attempt: ".$text);
                        die();
                }
//              die($text);
                return $text;
        }
}

$db = new db();
$url = new url();
```

my problem is, that this line

```
$result = mysql_query(self::protect($query)) or _log("Query failed: ".$query);
```

works, but when I change `self::` with `$this->` it's throwing error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method url::protect() in /data/my/db.php on line 71
```

how is it possible? I thought that `$this->function();` calls method in current class. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$this` refers to the current instance of the object. You're using `db` as a static class, thus there is no instance. Using `self` is fine. Why do you insist on using `$this`?

Comment: I was creating browser game and I never used static classes. but I like that -> in $this-> ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `url` constructor, you're calling `db::query` statically, therefore, `protect()` will be called statically as well and, hence, `$this` will not be available.

You can either keep it all static or you can inject an instance of `db` into `url`:

```
$db = new db();
$url = new url($db);
```

Comment: so I need to globalize $db and call it though $db->query(); ?

Comment: Not necessarily - there is no reason not to use db as a static class in this context.

Comment: @webbiedave: is there difference between injecting and globalizing?

Comment: Injection is favored above globalizing. Simply pass an instance of $db to $url and have $url store it in a private member. Or, as I mentioned, keep it all static.

Answer (score 1):

When using `db::query()`, you are accessing db in a static way (you are calling a class method, instead of an instance method).  Therefore, there is nothing to access via $this, as $this returns the pointer to a class instance, while `self` is a reference to the class itself.

If you would use `$db->query()`, `$this->protect()` would also work.

Comment: I heard that I SHOULD not globalize variables in function. Is that true/another way ?

Comment: You can always declare $db as an instance variable of class url, or pass it as a parameter.  But as I said above - why do you insist on making db a class instance?  It does not hold any variables, and you are unlikely to have more than one database.  It is perfectly fine to use a static class in this context.

Comment: I always use(d) instances, no metter what I did. could you come with me to discussion room?